# scan two worksheet in one workbook using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

Hi I'm having a problem about scanning my workbook, there are two worksheet need to scan.. 
The last thing I did is I scan the first worksheet but the second one is still not included.
here's my sample code :

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
reportpath = filename
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(reportpath)
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
```

Comment: What does your code do? It doesn't seem helpful

Comment: What do you mean with "scan"? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Sir andrey , the code is to do for opening the worksheet, I tried this one and it works xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1") but when I try to open two worksheet it's now working. How can I open same worksheet in one workbook?

Comment: Sir Peter, scan. I want to scan all files in excel that will be inserted on database. I want to scan two worksheet at the same time.

Comment: So you want 'scan' it or open it? Please, clarify, what do you want to achieve

Comment: Sir andrey, I want to scan it.. Scan the two worksheet

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbookv
Dim xlWorkSheet1 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlWorkSheet2 As Excel.Worksheet
xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
reportpath = filename
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(reportpath)
xlWorkSheet1 = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
xlWorkSheet2 = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

For i = 1 To 10
    MsgBox(xlWorkSheet1.Range("A" & i))
Next i
```

By using this code you're 'scanning' first 10 rows of column `A` of `Sheet1`.

Do the same with `xlWorkSheet2` if you want to 'scan' `Sheet2`

Answer (score 0):

Check this [tutorial](http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_oledb.htm) to get data from excel, and treated in a DataTable , this way is faster than with :

*Dim xlApp As Excel.Application*

*Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook*
*...*

or check my way:

Dim _con As OleDbConnection

```
Dim _cmd As New OleDbCommand

    Dim DtSet As DataSet

    Dim _tabExtrato as new DataTable

    Dim _adaptCommand As OleDbDataAdapter
```

Private Sub _readXLS(ByVal TXT As TextBox, 
              ByVal _linkFILE As String, 
              ByVal _folha As String, 
              ByVal DGV As DataGridView)

```
    _con = New OleDbConnection _
    ("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source='" & _linkFILE & "'; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")

    Dim trimTxt As String = "SELECT * FROM "

    '_folha = the sheet
    Dim _sqlQuery As String = " " & trimTxt & " [" & _folha & "$] "

    _adaptCommand = New OleDbDataAdapter(_sqlQuery, _con)

    _adaptCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "DSTable")

    DtSet = New DataSet

    '_adaptCommand.Fill(DtSet)
    _adaptCommand.Fill(_tabExtrato)

    DGV.DataSource = _tabExtrato

    _con.Close()

End Sub
```